# Rewrite the expression $a^{n-1}b^{n}-a^{n}b^{n-1}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am a computational, high-speed aerodynamics student.

Somewhere through my calculations, I came upon an ugly expression of this kind: (simplified version)

$f=C \left[(a^{n-1})b^{n} - a^{n}(b^{n-1})\right]=C\cdot h(a,b,n)$

I am trying to think of way to simplify the function $h(a,b,n)$ so as to turn it into a more manageable function. Is it possible such a task?

Comment: $$(a^{n-1})b^{n} - a^{n}(b^{n-1}) = (ab)^{n-1}(b-a)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both terms in the the $h$ expression contain $(ab)^{n-1}$, so you can factor it out:
$$(a^{n-1})b^{n} - a^{n}(b^{n-1}) = (a^{n-1})(b^{n-1})b-(a^{n-1})(b^{n-1})a= (ab)^{n-1}(b-a)$$